# How do I use the "+" operator to concatenate two strings?

Tags: javascript, string, date, google-earth-engine

In Google Earth Engine I need to generate a file name from a `ee.Date` object.
I have the following code in Google Earth Engine:

```
var date_object = ee.Date.fromYMD(2017,12, 1);
var date_string = date_object.format("YYYY-MM-dd");
print(date_string);
file_name = "my_file_" + date_string;
print(file_name);
```

The output of `print(date_string)` looks OK:

```
2017-12-01
```

But the output of print(file_name) is:

```
    ee.String({
    "type": "Invocation",
    "arguments": {
        "date": {
          "type": "Invocation",
          "arguments": {
            "year": 2017,
            "month": 12,
            "day": 1
          },
          "functionName": "Date.fromYMD"
        },
        "format": "YYYY-MM-dd"
      },
      "functionName": "Date.format"
    })
```

I expected I would get the output `my_file_2017-12-01`. How do I use the "+" operator with `ee.String` object in Google EarthEngine to concatenate two strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see is a proxy. This is explained in the following documentation page: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server. Adding getInfo() fixes the error:

```js
file_name = "my_file_" + date_string.getInfo();
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e61868ab3f333e8f2d19afd96b396964

And for the server-side EE code, as suggested by Nick:

```js
file_name = ee.String('my_file_').cat(date_string);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4812bb27a2869bd71771b067abd410e0

Comment: In your example it might be better to include the `getInfo()` function rather than copying over the same mistake OP is making :)

Comment: Alternatively, for a server-side string: `ee.String("my_file_").cat(date_string)`